# Вычисление значений функции

Tags: pascal

```
program second;
uses crt;
var x,y,d:real;
begin
 write('Введите значение x ');
 read(x);
 y:=-5*x+13;
 if y>0 then
  begin
   write('Введите значение шага преращения ');
   read(d);
  end;
 while y>0 do
  begin
   x:=x+d;
   y:=-5*x+13;
  end;
 write(y)
end.
```

Не могу понять, в чем моя ошибка. Данные для проверки -2 и 0.1.

Comment: Что хотели и что получили?

Comment: kogda vivodish text pomoemu nujno napisat writeln('Text'); poprobuy tak esli ne polucitsa napishi

Comment: Вроде нужно найти значение y вида y=-5*(x+d)+13, где d шаг преращения, до отрицательного значения. Беда в том, что задание я помню лишь примерно

Comment: Спасибо, но существенных различий между write и writeln, насколько я знаю, нет.

Comment: voobsheto write() dla peremennoy,a writeln() dla texta

Comment: writeln() - переводит на следующую строку а write() не переводит. вот и вся разница.

Comment: aaa da))sorry ya davno na pascale ne programmiruyu,ya srazu v delphi pereprignul))

Comment: я 6 лет его в глаза не видел и что? :)

Comment: posle write(y) postav eto ;

Comment: @Исмаил, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: Не обязательно ставить ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну зацикливание как я понимаю происходит.
Не ленитесь и возьмите сами свои данные и пробегите с ними и рядом записывая на бумаге результат увидите причину.
первая же подстановка -2 дает зацикливание в случае while

```
begin
 write('Введите значение x ');
 read(x); // -2
 y:=-5*x+13; 23
 if y>0 then // ок прошли дальше
  begin
   write('Введите значение шага преращения ');
   read(d); 
  end;
 while y>0 do // до сих пор значение 23 пошли по циклу и зациклились
  begin
   x:=x+d;
   y:=-5*x+13;
  end; 
 write(y)
end.
```

вопрос решен? если нет то измени цикл, он тебе нифиг не нужен на условие **if**

Честно логика написания твоего кода вообще непонятна.

Ну вот первый if ты проверил, прошло условие, а если не прошло, то что должно происходить ? просто идем дальше по коду, это неправильно. ну и т.д.

что должна делать эта маленькая и непонятная программа?

Comment: А как же x:=x+d ?

Comment: не увидел. убрал. обновил ответ.

Comment: Смотри, я первый раз просчитал, если получилось сразу отрицательное значение, можно все пропустить и вывести y. Если же нет, то нужно прибавлять 0,1(или другой шаг преращения) прибавлять к x до тех пор, пока y не станет меньше нуля

Comment: значит измени условие. у тебя есть if then добавь еще и else и в этот else впиши while

Comment: Это не тот случай, в else можно разве что добавить write(y)

Comment: нет, тогда придется еще и goto метки добавлять, а это буэээ

Comment: Ну да *-*-